# Modelling workflow with a periodic job on top of Cadence

Tags: workflow, cadence-workflow

**Use case:**

I have an entity(order item) to which a user subscribes.

The entity becomes available once in every month let's say, until the user removes the entity from his list or the entity is no longer valid, say the subscription expired.

So the valid states an entity can be in are Available, Stopped, Terminated.

When the entity is in available state, I want to check if it can be converted to an order by calling an external API (periodically) and if yes, call another API to create an order. These APIs are guaranteed to be idempotent in nature.

An entity could be stopped in between the subscription period and made available after a while.

**My approach:**

I am wrapping the APIs in Spring MVC from where I maintain a Parent workflow which holds the references for all Child workflows for individual entities.

The layer exposes the following API
POST (EntityId, State)
which calls the parent workflow , which does a lookup in its dictionary and then passes the necessary action by referencing the Child workflow.

Each child workflow can be signalled to be pushed into the aforementioned states and they additionally expose a query to their current state.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way this could be modelled better?
2. If instead I have to change the polling period like once in a month externally, is there a way I could that? Since updates are not allowed in workflows, and Thread.sleep() inside an activity would not be recommended wait what would be the most efficient of accomplishing that?

I am very new to writing workflows, please suggest if there are any mistakes I have made.

Comment: Join Cadence slack channel to discuss in more details: https://join.slack.com/t/uber-cadence/shared_invite/enQtNDczNTgxMjYxNDEzLTQyYjcxZDM2YTIxMTZkMzQ0NjgxYmI3OWY5ODhiOTliM2I5MzA4NTM4MjU4YzgzZDkwNGEzOTUzNTBlNDk3Yjc

Answer (score 0):

1. If number of entities per user is bounded then you can keep all of them in a single workflow. Having children in this case might add unnecessary complexity.
2. I don't understand what you mean by "updates are not allowed in workflows". Workflows can change their state any time. To change the period I would send a signal with a period to the workflow and it would update the period based on this signal information.